# When running a async lambda, use Task.Run(func) or new Func<Task>(func)()?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I want to collect/run tasks, and then do `Task.WhenAll` on them.

```
var tasks = new List<Task>();
foreach (var thing in things) {
  tasks.Add(Task.Run(async () => {
       // async stuff using thing
  }));
}

var stuffs = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Is it correct to use `Task.Run` here or should I do

```
tasks.Add(new Func<Task>(async () => {async stuff})());
```

Or something else entirely?

Comment: What type are `things`?

Comment: tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {//Do stuff});
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

That will start said task and add it to the list. Then what all tasks have been added, it will sit on the await line until all have completed.

Comment: @ZexksMarquise [StartNew is dangerous](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html), especially here where his `//do stuff` contains the `await` keyword. StartNew does not handle anonymous functions declared `async`

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Notice I didn't async DoStuff. Unless he's going to await something inside of DoStuff it's not needed. The await on WhenAll is enough to hold until the list of tasks is finished.

Comment: @ZexksMarquise Ok, and what about not passing in a `TaskScheduler`? when you don't specify one it uses `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext` which can make your task from `StartNew` run on the UI thread instead of a background thread if you are doing this from inside a task already on the background. The article I linked to describes this issue.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain It all depends on his needs. Also per the article you linked:

As a side note, the context of this discussion is async code. If you’re writing parallel code (e.g., dynamic task-based parallelism), then StartNew is the tool you want to use.

It all depends.

Comment: @ZexksMarquise I am not arguing StartNew vs not StartNew, I am arguing StartNew vs Task.Run. If you would have said `tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => {//Do stuff}); await Task.WhenAll(tasks);` I would have not mentioned a thing.

Comment: Side note to OP, depending on the nature of the work happening asynchronously, you should consider Parallel.ForEach. Cleaner syntax and a significant amount of behind the scenes .Net optimization for best threading.

Comment: thanks guys for the comments, in my case i didn't need parallel code as i'm not doing heavy CPU work, just async IO. for my case `new Func<Task>` was the appropriate solution, avoiding `Task.Run` and `Task.Factory.StartNew` altogether :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It usually depends on nature of your async work. If you do something like:

```
async () => {
   // some heavy CPU work here
   // then some IO
}
```

It's better to use `Task.Run`, because otherwise "heavy CPU work" will run on your current thread and you will gain little parallelization.

However, such situation is relatively rare, because for parallelization of heavy CPU work there are other tools. If you have something like this:

```
async () => {
   // some async IO, like database call or web request
   // some processing
   // some more async IO
}
```

Then you don't need to `Task.Run`. Then you can use your second method:

```
Func<Task> t = async () => {
     // some stuff
};
tasks.Add(t());
```

If you are doing that on UI thread (in WPF\WinForms) - ensure to use `ConfigureAwait(false)` inside your async delegate to prevent returning control to UI thread.

Comment: Understood, thanks! Wasn't entirely sure what the difference was but you cleared it up perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to [Evk's response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47401129/674237), it's also important to be aware of the potential differences in parallelism and if you need to think about thread-safety.

If all of the conditions below are true, then "func" does not need to be thread-safe:

- You use the `new Func` approach
- You don't use `ConfigureAwait(false)`
- The `SynchronizationContext` is a synchronizing context, meaning that it guarantees only one thread can execute code at a time (as in legacy ASP.NET)

Else, you need to think about the thread-safety of "func".